# What does 'thingy' in the context of 'Happy Thingy Birthday' refer to?

Tags: meaning

Currently staying in Bali, had a birthday, staff decorated with ballons saying "Happy Thingy Birthday". Is this common in (Asian) English? What does *thingy* mean in this context?

Comment: Something lost in translation, perhaps?

Comment: Possibly meant as a substitute for the number, since they don't know your age?

Comment: Euphemism for penis?

Comment: Seems like something lost in translation and no real meaning... Thanks for all replies!